# How to order and merge many .ts files?

Tags: video, macos

I have many small files (about 500). They are in right order. I would like to merge them. 
Linux commands are also welcome because I can compile them in my OS X. 
The command `cat *.ts > masi.ts` does not work well. The result stops at some points. I am investigating why this occurs. 
Some parts of the videos are not in order.

Names of parts of videos where each file has a prefix `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4.ts`

```
1.ts
2.ts
...
100.ts
101.ts
...
200.ts
...
300.ts
```

so the filename is `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-01.ts` ... `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-300.ts`.
The command `cat *.ts > masi.ts` does not organise the video in the sequential order. 
I think I should make a list before of all items in order. 
Then, merge.

Pseudocode

1. Make a list of videos in order
2. Merge `cat items in list`

   - Do something like `filename = prefix + itemInList` without creating a new list in the while loop.
   - `cat filename >> result.ts`

---

How can you join the many video files, .ts, files?

Comment: Not at all sure if this would work however you could try first with just a few files, have you tried concatenating then with `cat`?

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for the proposal! There are some bugs. Some gaps in some stages, which I do not understand. I will record the flash show once again and then test again. Sometimes, the order of videos are mixed, probably because of naming.

Comment: Are the only numbers in `itemInList` with a leading 0 (zero) e.g., 01...09 and what it the actual file number total count?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need to preface this by saying having not worked with `.ts` files I do not know whether or not they can be simply concatenated using `cat` and as you saw because the are numerically named they get mixed up when using `cat *.ts > masi.ts` because it sorts lexicographically, so using a ordered list is in order.  With that in mind, here is what I did to create a list of 500 numerically named `.ts` files and then concatenate them using the list.

I first created 500 numerically named `.ts` files containing the number of the `.ts` filename as a control.  I used `for i in {1..500}; do echo $i > $i.ts; done`  These weren't actually valid `.ts` files however it allowed me to have 500 files to work with and then see that they were concatenated in proper order when opening the `combined.ts` file to see an ordered numerical list within the file.

Since you already have the 500 `.ts` files, in Terminal do the following:

```
cd ts_files_directory
echo {1..500}.ts | tr " " "\n" > tslist
while read line; do cat $line >> combined.ts; done < tslist
```

**Updated to include actual filename per your comment to my answer and your updated question.**

The following assumes that the only numbers in `itemInList` with a leading 0 (zero)  are e.g., 01...09 and that you change `500` in the `{100..500}` portion  of the command to the actual *count*.

Change directory to that of which contains the `.ts` files.

```
cd ts_files_directory
```

The following two commands create the `tslist` file which is a numerically ordered list of the target filenames to be used with `cat` in order to avoid the lexicographical sorting issue.

```
echo 'HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-'{01..99}.ts | tr " " "\n" > tslist
echo 'HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-'{100..500}.ts | tr " " "\n" >> tslist
```

With the numerically ordered list created, use the following command line to concatenate based on the contents of the `tslist` file.

```
while read line; do cat $line >> combined.ts; done < tslist
```

Comment: The filename actually contains also `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-`. So concatenate is required. I run unsuccessfully `do cat "HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-" $line"`. Also failure in `echo "HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-" {1...500}`. What do you think where it is best to concatenate the prefix to the items of list? I think it is not smart to include the string in the list items, taking much space in reality. I think it is better to concatenate then lastly in do cat somehow.

Comment: Great! It seems to work. I need to add some globs by `echo 'HRmasi453-2701201?.mp4-'{01..99}.ts | tr " " "\n" > tslist`.

Comment: I extended the thread to the quality assurance. I am studying the quality assurance of the video merging here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258113/16920

Comment: @Masi, If the filenames were as you showed and stated up to the last `-`, e.g. `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4-`, then I fail to see why you needed to change it to `'HRmasi453-2701201?.mp4-`.  That said, nonetheless I'm glad you were able to use what I presented.  Additionally I'd like to add that if you'd give more accurate and more complete information when asking a question then it would be much easier to give accurate to the situation answers.  Just a thought. :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I do my best to give so clear details of the cases as I can. Often, however, the case evolves when I understand it better after the interaction with You. Therefore, I feel responsible in editing and updating the case so clear that you can benefit too. Therefore, I also extended the case into a new thread because I feel responsible in sharing the pieces of knowledge that I learned in applying the code in my challenges. They actually are more challenging than I ever thought but manageable.

Comment: As a side note, if you're want to read in the list of `ts` files by their timestamp, you can change line 2 above to `ls -tr *.ts | tr " " "\n" > tsList`

Answer (score 1):

Very easy way based in ffmpeg docs; the accepted answer is more complicated.

1. first print all the list of files in a file: mylist.txt , give the extension for your file, here is .ts

   ```
   printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.ts > mylist.txt
   ```
2. finally join the file using the txt list, last parameter name file joined, use same extension that the sources files.

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.ts
   ```

more info about concatenate:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: Can you please compare your answer to user3439894's one?

Comment: what do you mean? my answer is simple base in ffmpeg docs

Comment: `printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.ts > mylist.txt` fails for the exact same reason the OP was posted in the first place. `mylist.txt` will not contain a properly ordered list of `.ts` files because of how they are named and the video will be corrupted because the `.ts` files in the list are out of order. See this link for the contents of mylist.txt: https://paste.ee/p/ufu0S

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz 준영, See my comment to stackdave's answer.

Comment: just let the other people to judge with upvote or downvote, don't lost your time

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not done this myself I have seen discussions where people have combined multiple video files using the command line version of FFMPEG.

I believe there is a Mac version so you don't have to compile it from source on ffmpeg.org but beyond that someone else will have to verify that and help you with the proper command syntax.

Answer (score -1):

cat ?.ts ??.ts ???.ts > all.ts

Comment: According to the question, all files have a prefix of `HRmasi453-27012016.mp4.ts`, so the wildcards used may need some refinement here.

Answer (score -1):

I understand you are looking for a elegant command line solution.  However, if you use MKVToolnix, you can load the first TS file and append (merge) an unlimited number of ts files to be muxed subsequently in order into an mkv (for example 10, 5 second ts videos will mux into a 50 second mkv).  You can then mux the mkv back to a ts in tsmuxergui.